# O que são web workers e como utilizá-los

Tags: javascript, mvc, design-pattern

Através de pesquisas entendi que Web Workers permitem a simultaneidade de processos no JavaScript. Seria como disparar uma *thread* JavaScript que atualiza a *View*.

Pode-se considerar que seria a adaptação do padrão *MVC* ao JavaScript? Gostaria de mais informações e principalmente quais os cuidados no seu uso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De fato, um *Web Worker* é similar a um *thread* separado do principal. Entretanto, ele é completamente isolado tanto deste quanto do DOM (i.e. da *"View"*), de modo que a única forma de comunicação entre ele e a *thread* principal é através do uso de `postMessage`. Além do DOM, ele também não tem acesso a outras funcionalidades e variáveis/funções/classes globais disponíveis aos scripts comuns.

A principal utilidade de um Web Worker é separar em um *thread*/processo separado qualquer processamento pesado/demorado que de outra forma bloquearia totalmente a página até que o mesmo estivesse concluído. Um exemplo de uso seria:

script_normal.js

```
// Cria o web worker
var worker = new Worker('web_worker.js');

// Diz o que fazer quando o web worker enviar uma mensagem
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var dados = e.data;
    alert("O resultado é: " + dados.resultado);
});

// Manda uma mensagem pro web worker
worker.postMessage({ cmd:"acharPrimo", n:100 }); // assíncrono - retorna imediatamente
```

web_worker.js

```
// Diz o que fazer quando outro thread enviar uma mensagem
addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var dados = e.data;
    if ( dados.cmd == "acharPrimo" ) {
        var ret = acharPrimo(dados.n); // Chama uma função demorada
        postMessage({ resultado:ret }); // Manda o resultado como mensagem
    }
    // Outras funções, se aplicável
});

function acharPrimo(n) {
    // Acha o n-ésimo primo, construindo um crivo, etc...
}
```

Ou seja, quando a página inicia o processo demorado, ela não "trava" até que esse processo esteja pronto - você pode continuar utilizando-a, da mesma forma que o faria se tivesse feito uma chamada Ajax pro servidor (exceto que, nesse caso, tudo está acontecendo no próprio *browser*). Esse processo ocorre em paralelo e, ao terminar, envia os resultados para a página (em um evento também assíncrono) que pode então fazer alguma coisa com ele. Tanto a página quanto o *worker* podem mandar múltiplas mensagens um pro outro - por exemplo, para exibir ao usuário uma barra de progresso.

Um cuidado que é preciso ter com seu uso é no envio de mensagens: o *thread* principal e o *worker* possuem espaço de endereçamento separados (i.e. não compartilham memória). Isso significa que todo dado passado de um para o outro é **serializado** em uma string antes de ser enviado. No exemplo mostrado, quando se passou:

```
{ cmd:"acharPrimo", n:100 }
```

pro *worker*, não foi um objeto que foi passado, e sim uma string representando esse objeto. No caso, o objeto era pequeno, mas se fosse algo bem grande (tipo um array com vários elementos) a sua cópia de um para o outro - mediante representação em string, ainda por cima - poderia ter um impacto significativo na performance. Há uma alternativa - ainda não amplamente suportada, pelo menos da última vez que eu chequei - que seria o uso de [*transferables*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Advanced_concepts_and_examples#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_%28transferable_objects%29), objetos cuja "propriedade" é transferida de um *thread* para outro. Ou seja, o mesmo objeto que antes estava em um *thread* agora passa a estar em outro, tornando-se inacessível ao primeiro, mas sem que ocorra cópia alguma.

Outro cuidado necessário seria lembrar que o *web worker* em si é *single-threaded*, ou seja: depois que um processo demorado começou, ele tem de ir até o final antes de outro começar. Ele pode mandar mensagens para o *thread* principal à vontade, mas a recíproca não é verdadeira: enquanto esse código não terminar de executar, mensagens mandadas ao *worker* serão enfileiradas até que o mesmo esteja disponível.

Um corolário é que não dá para "matar" o processo mandando uma mensagem de *stop* para ele - pois essa mensagem só seria recebida depois que o processo já terminou mesmo... Num caso desses, seria preferível que seu *worker* só executasse uma única iteração do loop por vez, pausando antes de executar a próxima (dando tempo para que as mensagens pendentes fossem processadas). E, é claro, se você possui dois ou mais processamentos a realizar, ou você cria dois *workers* ou garante que um deles está ocioso antes de reutilizá-lo (um *pool* de *workers* é melhor que criar sempre um novo, pois elimina o *overhead* da criação).

Por fim, convém citar que um `WebWorker` comum só está acessível ao *thread* que o criou (seja o principal, ou outro *web worker*), mas é possível compartilhar um *worker* com outros através do uso de um [`SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker). Sua funcionalidade é bastante similar a de um *worker* comum, mas sua API possui algumas diferenças, em especial na forma de um *thread* se comunicar com outro.

Comment: Claro, conciso e esclarecedor! Obrigado! Só mais uma questão, onde consigo me informar a partir de quais versões os browsers suportam _Web Worker_?

Comment: @Jota [Na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) (tabela de compatibilidade no fim da página).

Comment: @Jota Conforme o [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=webworker) todos os *browsers* exceto IE9 ou anterior dão suporte. `SharedWorker`, por outro lado, [somente Chrome e Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers). Não tenho informação sobre *transferables*...

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.