# Um script começa a executar somente depois do outro ou ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: javascript, html

Se eu carregar dois scripts pelo html o segundo vai começar a executar somente após o primeiro ter carregado ou ao mesmo tempo que o primeiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta pode ter várias interpretações. Pelo que eu entendi você quer saber se incluindo 2 scripts com a tag `script`, ele vai executar um após o outro. Abstraindo, a resposta seria sim. Diversos fatores podem fazer com que o segundo execute primeiro. Um exemplo disso é se você botar o atributo `async` na tag `script`, aí o navegador que vai gerenciar qual executa primeiro.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que o html é por padrão synchrono pra tudo?

Comment: @ViniciusPuttiMorais sim.

Answer (score 1):

Os scripts serão executados na ordem em que são carregados. Javascript por padrão é síncrono.

Note que isso não significa que toda a lógica de um script será executada imediatamente quando ele for carregado. Se você faz algo do tipo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        console.log("Script 1");
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Script 2");
</script>
<!---->
```

Você poderá ver no console primeiro "script 2", depois "script 1". O primeiro script de fato executou primeiro, mas a parte onde ele escreve no console fica em espera até que o DOM esteja pronto.

Note que algumas pessoas podem dizer que `Ajax`, `setInterval`, `setTimeout` etc. permitem programação assíncrona. Se você trabalhar apenas com essas coisas você ainda utilizará apenas uma única thread para o seu código. Para executar threads de forma simultânea você vai precisar de [Web Workers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46926/o-que-s%C3%A3o-web-workers-e-como-utiliz%C3%A1-los/).