# Qual é a diferença entre Service Worker e Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu estava lendo na MDN e percebi que, além dos [Webworkers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46926), existem também os [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Inclusive tem esse código de exemplo:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw-test/sw.js', {scope: '/sw-test/'})
  .then(function(reg) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
```

- Basicamente, qual é a diferença entre ambos?
- Quando devo usar um Web Worker ou um Service Worker?
- Atualmente podemos implementar sem preocupações com suporte dos navegadores¹?

<sub>¹ pergunta está sendo feita em 2017</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Basicamente, qual é a diferença entre ambos?

Basicamente Web Worker foi projetado para executar funções de alto consumo sem que isso interfira na execução do código principal ou seja, não bloqueie o ciclo principal do evento visto que ele ocorre em paralelo. Scripts Web Worker não interceptam os pedidos da rede e se comunicam explicitamente através de mensagens.

Já Service Worker foi projetado para interceptar os pedidos de rede que normalmente requisitam aquivos como imagens, scripts e recursos estáticos afim de armazená-los em cache e utilizá-los posteriormente em redes instáveis ou mesmo na falta da rede (offline) de modo a não interromper a execução do código principal. Vale apena resaltar que Service Worker é o padrão sucessor do já depreciado [AppCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) e é um dos pilares fundamentais para o **offline-first** bem como vem sendo cada vez mais utilizado para acelerar futuros acessos á aplicação.

> Quando devo usar um Web Worker ou um Service Worker?

Este ponto é um tanto quanto subjetivo más talvez seja possível afirmar que operações mais intensas devem ser executadas em um Web Worker exemplo:

Imagine o caso de receber o formato `PCM` de uma gravação do microfone e codificar em no formato `RAW` usando por exemplo algum porte do `LibeLame` (.mp3) em javascript para enviar ao servidor, este processo torna-se custoso e ao ser executado no código principal bloquearia o evento principal fazendo com que interações e processos decorrentes só fossem executadas após a conclusão deste evento. Ao utilizar esta parte do código em um Web Worker o código principal não necessitaria ser bloqueado e apenas "escutaria" o resultado deste processo por meio de mensagem.

Já Service Worker é mais indicado nos casos em que a aplicação deva estar disponível mesmo na falha (ou falta) da rede (offline) ou simplesmente para acelerar o carregamento da página/aplicação exemplo:

Se sua página/aplicação possui muitos recursos como **fontes, css, javascript ou outros (json, xml, csv)** que não necessitam serem atualizadas com tanta frequência más que tem um custo considerável para o carregamento da página, considere utilizar Service Worker com a seguinte estratégia:

- 1: se não esta em cache... armazene-o
- 2: se já esta em cache... verifique se há alguma versão posterior (e atualize o cache)
- 3: sirva o conteúdo em cache

Observe que os recursos provenientes do cache não necessitam de download da rede e por isso são "acomodados" ao DOM mais rápido e por isso trazem um efeito final de uma renderização muito mais rápida.

Se a necessidade for exclusivamente servir uma aplicação **"offline"** Service Worker pode armazenar todos os tipos de recursos obtidos através de uma requisição `GET` inclusive requisições `cross-origem` a única ressalva a ser posta aqui é utilizar uma estratégia adequada as necessidades da aplicação.

> Atualmente podemos implementar sem preocupações com suporte dos navegadores?

Web Worker é atualmente suportado pelos principais navegadores e segundo [whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html) ele este disponível sobre um ciclo **"LS"** (Living Standard) o quadro abaixo demostra o suporte dos principais navegadores (segundo [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=webworker)).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Service Worker por sua vez é uma especificação no processo de definição atualmente encontra-se em **"WD"** (rascunho) segundo [w3c](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/).

Seu suporte e implementação estão atualmente mais avançados em **Chrome** e **Firefox** nas suas respectivas versões "desktop" e "mobile"... outros navegadores também o suportam mas de maneira parcial ou através da ativação de "bandeiras" nas configurações de recursos do navegador. O quadro abaixo demostra o suporte nos principais navegadores segundo o site [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=serviceworker).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

De maneira simples é possível utilizar Service Worker nos principais navegadores de maneira total ou parcial más isso depende em muito da abordagem em questão.

---

**edição (30/11/2017):**

Para aqueles interessados em acompanhar o progresso da implementação de Service Worker nos principais navegadores (Chrome, Firefox, Samsung Internet, Safari e Edge) vale a pena dar uma olhada na página mantida por [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/). Nela é possível acompanhar em quais navegadores e suas versões as "features" de Service Worker estão disponíveis.